# Make Target Name From Another

Tags: makefile

Have problem in dynamically "create" target name with *.SECONDEXPANSION:*

Small **Makefile** to reproduce problem:

```
CONFIGS = test1 test2 test3

.SECONDEXPANSION:

all: $(CONFIGS)

OBJECTS=$$(CFG_NAME)_OBJECTS


$(CONFIGS) : CFG_NAME=$@
$(CONFIGS) : $(OBJECTS) 
    @echo $(CFG_NAME) $@ from $^

$(OBJECTS):
    @echo OBJECTS $@ from $^
    @echo DO IT
```

It says: "No rule to make target 'test1_OBJECTS'.
How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT: CHANGE OF THE ANSWER**

Thank you much for the answer. It was the simple variant for my task.

So I try to answer in another way.

```
CONFIGS = test1 test2 test3
PLATFORMS = x86 ppc arm
#will be test1x86 test2x86 ... test1ppc ... test3arm,
#so it is long way to enumarate all variants
VARIANTS = $(foreach c, $(CONFIGS), $(foreach p, $(PLATFORMS), $(c)$(p)))
#C FILE LIST
CFILES:=$(shell /bin/find -name "*.c")


.SECONDEXPANSION:

all: $(VARIANTS)

#More Comlex Rule
#Want to corresponding objects be in bins/test1x86/
OBJECTS:=$(CFILES:%.c=bins/$$(CFGNAME)%.o)


$(CONFIGS) : CFG_NAME=$@
$(CONFIGS) : $(OBJECTS) 
    @echo $(CFG_NAME) $@ from $^

#More complex prerequisites
#I understand that $$(CFGNAME) will be resolve incorrect.
#For each *.c file in subdir I would have object in corresponding path.
#For example, '1/2/3/test.c' will use for generate 
#object file 'bins/test1x86/1/2/3/test.o',
#when I call 'make testx86' or 'make all' (it will build all VARIANTS),
#in 'bins/test1x86/1/2/3/'.
#So what have I do?
$(OBJECTS): bins/$$(CFGNAME)_OBJECTS/%o : %.c
    @echo OBJECTS $@ from $^
    @echo DO IT
```

So, I would like to avoid recursive make calls. Can you help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotcha it.

```
CONFIGS = test1 test2 test3
PLATFORMS = p1 p2
#Will be testp1 test1p2 .. test3p2
VARIANTS = $(foreach c, $(CONFIGS), $(foreach p, $(PLATFORMS), $(c)$(p)))

.SECONDEXPANSION:
#.c files list in all subfolders
cfiles = $(shell /bin/find -name "*.c")
#objects for these .c files for custom VARIANT
objects = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(addprefix bins/$1/,$(cfiles)))
#Get .c source for object (e.g. bins/test1p1/tests/main_test.o => tests/main_test.c)
get_src=$(shell echo $1 | sed 's/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/\(.*\)/\1.c/')

#Build All Variants
all: $(VARIANTS)

#Build objects. Target list contains all objects for all variants.
#Prerequisites get .c sources from the pattern rule for targets
$(foreach v, $(VARIANTS), $(call objects,$(v))) : %.o : $$(call get_src,$$*)
    @echo OBJECTS $@ FROM $^

#Variants rule, depends on objects 
$(VARIANTS): $(call objects,$$@)
    @echo $@ from $^
```

Thank you, Beta. You only have tried. :)
Maybe anyone have style or efficiency suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a rule for `$(OBJECTS)`, but that target expands to `$(CFG_NAME)_OBJECTS`, which is *not* expanded again (ever), so it can't match anything. Try this instead:

```
test1_OBJECTS test2_OBJECTS test3_OBJECTS:
    @echo OBJECTS $@ from $^
    @echo DO IT
```

Or better:

```
OBJECT_SETS = $(addsuffix _OBJECTS, $(CONFIGS))

$(OBJECT_SETS):
    @echo OBJECTS $@ from $^
    @echo DO IT
```

(And I'm sure you realize your example doesn't really need `SECONDEXPANSION` at all.)

**EDIT:**

That should be a separate question, but I'll try to answer it here. (And please use punctuation in the comments in your makefile; they are very difficult to understand.)

There is more than one solution to your problem. Here is one:

```
vpath %.c $(dir $(CFILES))

CFILES := $(notdir $(CFILES))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My variant is more complex. So I have edited my question.

Comment: Hmmm, I think it will be another result.  CFILES will contain file list without directories. They will be search in all enumerated folders. What if we have file folder1/1.c and folder2/1.c? I do not understand this way.

Comment: @Camarada, maybe I misunderstood the comments in your makefile. If you have `folder1/1.c` and `folder2/1.c`, and you `make test1x86`, where do you want the *two different* `test11.o` files to go?

Comment: They will be in folder bins/test1x86/folder1/1.o and  bins/test1x86/folder2/1.o

Comment: I can't get solution so far, it is a big pity.